# How much does opening a TCP socket whenever you want to send a request impacting performance?

Tags: sockets, kotlin, tcp

What I am asking is, how much does opening a TCP socket `val socket: Socket("198.51.100.1", 9999)` always whenever you are going to send an request `socket.outputstream().write("Hello World!".toByteArray())` and then closing it `socket.close()` impact the performance of a program/an app? I am developing an app, which always opens a new socket using coroutines, however, the problem was at the end device, the ports were starting at 53000 (or something like that), so the ports for every socket would fill up very quickly.

I am asking, how would this impact performance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is very slow to initialize, due to the anti-congestion algorithm. Your concern should not be the ports (unless you are making a *lot* of requests and leaking connections), but the initialization time. If you can use keepalive sockets, that is much preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it viable to use a secondary Thread() to create a socket and then feed the socket to coroutines? Is it viable? Also could you please provide any resources to this? Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a workaround for the delay, just use https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html to launch the connection in the background. You can then continue to process stuff, and when you're ready to use the connection, you can call https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html to get the result of the connection (which really should be a Pair(ByteSendChannel, ByteReadChannel) or something similar) and do your work, closing it when done

Comment: I am not feeling any delay. I already used coroutines, do I need to create another one?

Comment: You asked about using a new thread so I assumed you wanted to mitigate the performance issues. The two solutions are to either 1) initialise the socket earlier, so that it is ready by the time you need it or 2) use UDP which doesn't have the anti-congestion delay.

Comment: I said new thread because you can't do networking on MainThread in Android.

Comment: Of course you have to use Dispatchers.IO. Anyway, you accepted the answer so if you don't need nuffin' more I'll begone

Comment: Yeah I kinda just wanted an answer to this. Thanks for this. I'll go fix it, now that it's wrong. Thank